# Download PDF in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am attempting to download a pdf file in ASP MVC using C#.

I have a UI-dialog with a button invoking the call to the controller:

```
 "Download PDF": function () {
            $.post(Urls.Action.DownloadPDF);
```

In the controller I am using a PDF converter to convert the html to PDF:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPDF()
     {
         string htmlToConvert = RenderViewAsString("~/Content/Eula.htm");
         HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
         byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlToConvert,null);
         HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Download.pdf");
         FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
         fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Download.pdf";

         return fileResult;
     }
```

The code runs through the method without issue in the debugger and the post returns successful but the browser is not downloading the PDF.

**EDIT -**

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   private, s-maxage=0,private,no-store,no-cache,s-maxage=0,max-age=0,must-revalidate,proxy-revalidate,no-transform
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Type    application/pdf
Expires -1
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie  
FB; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0
content-disposition attachment; filename=Download.pdf
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=Download.pdf
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
X-UA-Compatible IE=edge,chrome=1
Date    Fri, 07 Jun 2013 03:31:34 GMT
Content-Length  81862
```

Comment: "the browser is not downloading the PDF" isn't a very descriptive diagnosis. What does your browser's F12 tools say about network activity and headers sent? Do you want the browser to save the file (use `content-disposition`) or view it in the window?

Comment: I added the content disposition in earlier... please see the edit with the response header.

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller method should be something like this:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadPDF()
{
    string htmlToConvert = RenderViewAsString("~/Content/Eula.htm");

    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
    byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlToConvert,null);

    return File(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf", "Download.pdf");
}
```

I haven't had a whole lot of experience with file downloads but similar code works for me to download excel files.

I found [this post](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-mvc-action-results-and-pdf-content/) that specifically talks about downloading PDF's. It outline the difference between `ActionResult` and `FileResult` - `ActionResult` doesn't contain the content type. It also explains the different results that build on `FileResult`:

> If the content you want to transfer is stored within a disk file, you
>   can use the FilePathResult object. If your content is available
>   through a stream you use FileStreamResult and you opt for
>   FileContentResult if you have it available as a byte array. All these
>   objects derive from FileResult and differ from one another only in the
>   way that they write out data to the response stream.

**EDIT:** After a little searching, I believe I found the root of the problem. You may be able to use the same code, but you would need to call `WriteFile` to write the content to the response stream - using `File(...)` does that by default:

> The result object that is prepared by this method is written to the
>   response by the ASP.NET MVC framework when the object is executed.

See the MSDN docs for more info:

- [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.writefile%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)